# Is there a Spanish equivalent to "-ish"?

Tags: traducción, modismos

In English, we often add "-ish" to the end of a word to make it less exact.

Here are some examples:

> I'll be there at 5:00ish.
>   The shirt was a reddish color.
>   The woman appeared to be 50ish.

See [WikiDefinition for -ish](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ish) for more information.

Is there a way to translate this to Spanish without using a long phrase such as "más o menos" or "aproximadamente"?

Answer (score 31):

No. There's not a single way of translating it, hence the need for different options. I'm also from Spain and these are the most common ways of expressing it. The first one of each list is the most popular way of saying it.

### Time

Example: **I'll be there at 5:00ish**

Translations:

- Llegaré **sobre** las cinco. [One of the most common ways of saying it.]
- Llegaré a las cinco **y pico**. [This actually means AFTER 5.]
- Llegaré **a eso de** las cinco.
- Llegaré **hacia** las cinco.
- Llegaré **más o menos a** las cinco.
- Llegaré **alrededor de** las cinco.
- Llegaré **aproximadamente a** las cinco.
- Llegaré a las 5, **minutos más minutos menos**. [not used in Spain, see comments].

### Color

Example: **The shirt was a reddish colour**

Translations:

- La camiseta **tenía** un color **rojizo*** [Definitely the most used way of saying it.]
- La camiseta era de un color **tirando a rojo**
- La camiseta era de un color **más o menos rojo**
- La camiseta era de un color **parecido al rojo** [It implies that actually it wasn't red.]

*Each color has a termination. As shared by Blas Soriano and grouped by termination group: Azulado, Rosado, Anaranjado; Grisáceo, Violáceo; Parduzco, Negruzco, Verduzco/Verdoso, Blancuzco/Blanquecino; Purpúreo, Cerúleo; Rojizo; Amarillento. There's also a [picture](http://www.acearquitectos.com/archivos/501.jpg).

### Age

Example: The woman appeared to be 50ish

Translations (note that some *require* "años" and some can have that omitted):

- La mujer tendría **cincuenta y pico.**
- La mujer tendría **unos cincuenta.**
- La mujer tendría **alrededor de cincuenta** años.
- La mujer tendría **cuarenta y muchos.** [late fourties]
- La mujer tendría **cincuenta y pocos.** [early fifties]
- La mujer **estaría sobre los cincuenta.**
- La mujer tendría **más o menos cincuenta** años.

Comment: Esta debería ser una respuesta canónica! 
Solo agregaría *alrededor de* para cantidades enumerables (dinero, objetos hora) este tipo de construcción no aplicaría para colores por ejemplo:
El taxi llegará *alrededor de* las cinco 
Nos quedan en cuenta *alrededor de* 300 pesos
Ella tiene *alrededor de* 20 años 
Esa manada tiene *alrededor de* 20 bisontes

Comment: Otra construcción se puede hacer usando al final de la oración algo como **[unidad de medida] más, [unidad de medida] menos** que es equivalente y muy comprensible para los angloparlantes con su ***give or take*** al final de una oración por ejemplo: El taxi llegará a las 5; *minutos más, minutos menos* Nos quedan en cuenta 500 pesos, *centavos más, centavos menos* Etc...

Comment: @hlecuanda especifico que soy de España porque suponía que habría casos como este. Aquí nunca usaríamos esa expresión en los ejemplos que pones, la añado de todas formas con una nota.

Comment: Gracias, Francisco! La forma en que estructuraste la respuesta resulta bastante clara y concisa,. Por lo que agregar algunos regionalismos claramente indicados como lo has hecho, hace quer tu excelente respuesta, sea todavía mejor. Muchas gracias por incluir mis sugerencias.

Comment: Para el ejemplo de la edad, yo añadiría el (creo que más común, al menos en España) "cincuenta y tantos"

Comment: @JorgeUrreta ya está "cuarenta y muchos", "cincuenta y pico", y "cincuenta y pocos" que creo que ya se parecen lo bastante. "Cincuenta y tantos" sería más parecido a "mid-fifties" y no tanto a "50-ish", al menos comparado con las opciones que he propuesto.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia son todos equivalentes, sólo pretendo ampliar las opciones (de hecho, he votado por tu respuesta). "cincuenta y tantos", y "cincuenta y pocos" (y la mayoría, sino todas, de las opciones que planteas) son tanto equivalentes a "50-ish" como  a "50 something", dos formas más de decirlo mismo, ninguna necesariamente mejor que la otra.

Comment: Me gusta mucho *a eso de*.  Sí, es cierto que *como* es súper común en México, pero *a eso de las 5:00* es más bonito, y es suficientemente común.

Comment: La imagen enlazada manda a un 404

Answer (score 16):

The way I've heard it said in Nicaragua is with ***y pico***. In fact, [the WordReference page for *pico*](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=pico) almost exactly matches your examples:

> **tiene 50 y pico de años**: she's fifty odd or fifty something (colloq)
>
> **son las dos y pico**: it's past or gone two

WordReference doesn't mark it as a regionalism, so I assume it's fairly universal. As far as I know this only works with numerical values though, not with things like colors.

Comment: So true, I totally forgot about that one, it is also quite common in Mexico and I've also heard it in Argentina.

Comment: Pico is used almost everywhere in latin america, but Pico is used only for numbers just like the example mentioned by jrdioko

Comment: Yes, in Spain is also y pico, but not with age though.

Comment: @JoulSauron In Spain y pico is used with age too.

Comment: @Pablo you are right, shame on me. The problem is that the phrase jrdioko used didn't seem well to me, the way I would say is: "tiene 50 y pico años" or "50 años y pico".

Answer (score 14):

There are a lot of ways to translate -ish and, I'm afraid, it's going to be one of those "a thousand regionalisms" answer, I'm form Spain. It really depends on the example:

- I'll be there at 5:00ish --> Estaré allí (llegaré) **hacia/más o menos sobre/sobre** las cinco.
- The shirt was a reddish colour --> La camiseta era de color **rojizo/de un tono rojo/tirando a rojo/más o menos rojo**
- The woman appeared to be 50ish --> La mujer parecía tener **unos cincuenta/ estar sobre los cincuenta/ cuarenta y muchos cincuenta y pocos/más o menos cincuenta.**

The more general maybe is **más o menos** and I think it's always safe to use, sometimes could sound forced but it'll be understood.

Comment: For colours, it depends on the colour: rojizo, verdoso, azulado, amarillento. If you don't know this, you can use what @Laura say: "tirando a rojo/verde/azul/amarillo".

Comment: -1 The question specifically asks for a way to translate the -ish without a long phrase like the ones you propose.

Comment: @SergioRomero No, he is asking IF THERE IS a way, and there isn't.

http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=-ish

Comment: For the time, another way is "a eso de las cinco".

Comment: @JoulSauron: No, he is asking if there is a way WITHOUT USING A LONG PHRASE. So if there isn't the answer is No, there is no accurate translation. The only "sort of" way anybody has come with so far has been for colors.

Comment: @SergioRomero first of all I suggest a few that are not "long sentences" such "hacia" or "sobre". Maybe you're right and it's just a long way to answer "no". If more people suggest it as a bad answer I'll delete it, no problem.

Answer (score 7):

I've seen a very common use of the `-ón` termination, sometimes used with the word `algo` (some), like so:

```
El color de la camisa era algo rojón 
La camisa era algo rojona.
La mujer era cincuentona.
Juan es algo preocupón.
```

However, I do not know if these are good uses or regionalisms.

Another approach I've seen, probably taken from scientific naming of substances, are terminations `-ico`, `-ato`, `-oso`, `-ito`:

```
La camisa era rojosa.
La mujer aparentaba ser cincuentosa. (I still prefer "cincuentona" in here)
```

I'm sure there are more correct ways to express these, but they get the grip of the `-ish` approach.

Comment: I've never heard -ón for that, nor any of the sentences you wrote in Spain. For age, we use "cuarentón" and "cincuentón" (just with 40 and 50) to express middle-aged adults, usually in a pejoyaritve way for "in his/her fifties". The way to say it is: "es UN cuarentón", not "es cuarentón".

About colours, never heard "rojón". I said in the other answer that each colour has it's own way to say "-ish", and that's the way we use at least in Spain. I would like to hear more opinions about Latin-American Spanish-speakers on this.

Comment: I'm sure I've heard them. Thanks, you confirmed to me that they are, at the very least, regionalisms.

Comment: Never ever heard "rojón" ... "rojizo/a" is pretty common

Comment: The suffix is unrelated

Answer (score 6):

Even when there can be many translations and the following one will probably not be the best one from an academical point of view, I'd choose **"como"** (or optionally "como ~ o así") in the following way:

I'll be there at 5:00ish. => Estaré **como** a las cinco / Estaré **como** a las cinco o así.

The shirt was a reddish color. => La camiseta era **como** roja / La camiseta era **como** roja o asi

The woman appeared to be 50ish. => La mujer parecía tener **como** cincuenta / La mujer parecía tener **como** cincuenta o así

Comment: I am a native mexican spanish speaker and I think this is the reply that better answers the question. At least in Mexico "como" is very common.

Answer (score 2):

For completness i should mention a rather common construction (used in Argentina) that has the same colloquial meaning for *somewhat, proximity or likeness) that* -ish*  does have (with only a single word applied)

> ***tipo*** [ to imply the same that ***'más o menos'***, or ***'por ahí de'*** would do ]

So that

> I'll be there at 5:00ish
>
> The shirt was a reddish color.
>
> The woman appeared to be 50ish.

Could equivalently be said here as

> Estaré ahí ***tipo*** 5:00
>
> La remera era de un color ***tipo*** rojo
>
> La  mujer aparentaba tener ***tipo*** unos cincuenta años

Comment: Good to know -- I've never heard this!

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

**por ahí de**

Example:

> Voy a llegar por ahí de las 11.