# ¿Cuál es el sufijo "-uno" añadido a palabras como "viejuno" o "raruno"? ¿De dónde viene?

Tags: etimología, significado, españa, animales, sufijos

Palabras de creación reciente como *raruno* o *viejuno* usan un sufijo *-uno* que no logro identificar y que no aparece en el DLE. Estas palabras se van poco a poco abriendo hueco en el vocabulario del español (al menos en el europeo). Ejemplos:

- [17 síntomas de que eres un viejuno digital](https://www.xataka.com/especiales/13-sintomas-de-que-eres-un-viejuno-digital)
- [Algunos verbos «rarunos» sacados del baúl de las palabras](http://blogs.molinodeideas.com/cometario/algunos-verbos-rarunos-sacados-del-baul-de-las-palabras/)

No estoy muy seguro del origen de estas palabras, pero me da que programas de televisión como *La hora chanante* y *Muchachada nui* tuvieron bastante que ver con su difusión. En cuanto al significado de añadir este sufijo para formar derivados de adjetivos, me da la sensación de que es similar al *[-ish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2261/12637)* inglés, y por tanto "viejuno" sería "algo así como viejo pero sin llegar a serlo del todo".

Lo más parecido que he encontrado en el DLE son palabras como *[conejuno](https://dle.rae.es/conejuno)*, cuya segunda acepción es "semejante al conejo", lo que parece corroborar mi sospecha acerca de su significado. También está *[gatuno](https://dle.rae.es/gatuno)*, pero aquí la única acepción es "perteneciente o relativo al gato". Nótese además que en estos dos casos el sufijo afecta a un sustantivo, mientras que en los casos que me intrigan (*viejuno*, *raruno*) afecta a adjetivos.

Pregunto pues, ¿de dónde viene este sufijo *-uno*? ¿Cuál sería su etimología y significado?

Comment: significado probablemente, es un poco despectivo del sustantivo, etimología no sé

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Significado

> Spanish, for example, has a suffix, -uno, originally forming relational or similative adjectives only on the basis of animal nouns (e.g. lobuno ‘relating/similar to wolves’ ← lobo ‘wolf’). During the Renaissance, however, speakers also began applying this suffix to human bases, thereby implicitly assimilating the persons denoted to animals (e.g. lacayuno ‘relating/similar to servants’ ← lacayo ‘servant’).
>
> - [*The Oxford Handbook of Derivational Morphology*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=If2KBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA351&lpg=PA351&dq=spanish+suffix+uno)

### Etimología

Según Yakov Malkiel, viene del latín -UGNUS via:

- *CAPRUGO > CAPRU(G)NUS > CAPRUNUS

> CAPRUNUS persisted in a sizable zone, comprising all three major parts of the Iberian peninsula and Occitania. In this area it mustered sufficient power, as a result of the important, in part dominant role played by the goat in pastoral environment, to contaminate names of other domestic animals (the sheep, the donkey, the horse, the cow) with its characteristic ending -UNU, more specifically and narrowly classified than -INU.
>
> ...
>
> In Spanish, *-uno* gradually extended to the names of wild animals (*ovejuno* and *perruno* call to mind *lobuno*, since the sheep, the shepherd's dog, and the wolf are all participants in the same happenings), also to names of human beings, implicitly lowered, in the speaker's esteem, to the level of beasts, (was the label *moruno* not a sharp snap at the infidel, whom the medieval Christian world, in moments of tension, unhesitatingly likened to a dog or to a pig; cf. OSp. *judezno, morezno, pecadezno*?). In accord with its original restriction to a small group of useful animals, 44720, in substantivated formations, referred to hides and leathers; its continued service in denoting offensive smells (cf. It. *il caprino*) suggests that speakers were loath to forget the originator of the series, *cabruno*, in which the suffix is attached to the name of a much-dreaded offender.

- [The Latin Background of the Spanish Suffix -uno: Studies in the Genesis of a Romance Formative](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44939675), 1950
- [Nuevas aportaciones para el estudio del sufijo *-uno*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/40297442.pdf)

Comment: Cf. *hombruno* 'mannish'